# f bijection on some set $X$ with property $f(A) \subseteq A$, does $f(A) = A$ follow?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a very simple question I can't seem to figure out on my own. Let's say we have a bijection $f: X \rightarrow X$ on some set $X$ and we have a subset $A \subseteq X$ with the property $$f(A) \subseteq A$$ Does it follow that $$f(A) = A$$ ?

Comment: It is not true, take as an example $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=1/2+x/3$, it is easy to see $f([0,1]) = [1/2,5/6]\subsetneq [0,1]$

Comment: You would have to show that $A \subseteq f(A)$ as well, which, by your givens, we really have no information on that. And as you can see, there are various counterexamples already given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take $f(x)=2x$ for $x\in\Bbb R$. This is a bijection, and
$$f(\Bbb N)\subseteq \Bbb N$$
but $3\notin f(\Bbb N)$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider the map $x \mapsto x/2$ on the reals. (And, take for $A = [-1,1]$ for example.)

Answer (score 3):

With smallest possible input set: Consider $f\colon \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$, $x\mapsto x+1$, and $A=\mathbb N$